# how to get data after last slash of href= value and its alt= value for given big data string?

Tags: php, regex, parsing, preg-match-all

I have a big string that has mixture of two types of data sets. I want to get the data after the last slash in all href values (for example 168702 and 167504) and its corresponding `alt=` values (which is episode 29 and episode 20). I tried the following, but I can't get the correct data.

```
  preg_match_all('/<a  class=\"asite-thumbnail\" href="(.*?)"/s', $code2, $foo);
print_r($foo[1]);
```

first data set type:

```
  <a class="asite-thumbnail" href="/season/path/12345/1/168702"><img src="http://asite.image2432424.jpg" alt="Episode 29"><div class="asite-title">Episode 29</div><div class="asite-info">starwar season 2</div></a>
```

second data set type:

```
<a class="asite-thumbnail" title="episode 20 start war season 2" href="/season/path/12345/1/167504""><img src="http://asite.com/_thumb_dfsdfsdf.jpg" alt="episode 20">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can accomplish this using the domdocument...

```
$input = '<a class="asite-thumbnail" href="/season/path/12345/1/168702"><img src="http://asite.image2432424.jpg" alt="Episode 29"><div class="asite-title">Episode 29</div><div class="asite-info">starwar season 2</div></a>';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($input);
$links = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a'); // pull all links
foreach ($links as $link) { //loop through each link
    echo 'End of Link=' . preg_replace('~^.*/~', '', $link->getAttribute('href')) . "\n"; //strip down the url to all content after the last /
    $images = $link->getElementsByTagName('img');//get all images in the link
    foreach($images as $image) { //loop through all links
        echo 'Alt attribute = ' . $image->getAttribute('alt') . "\n"; // output the alt attributes content
    }
}
```

Output:

> End of Link=168702
>   Alt attribute = Episode 29

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/eW0zI1/1

... or using both data sets...

```
$input = '<a class="asite-thumbnail" href="/season/path/12345/1/168702"><img src="http://asite.image2432424.jpg" alt="Episode 29"><div class="asite-title">Episode 29</div><div class="asite-info">starwar season 2</div></a><a class="asite-thumbnail" title="episode 20 start war season 2" href="/season/path/12345/1/167504""><img src="http://asite.com/_thumb_dfsdfsdf.jpg" alt="episode 20">';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($input);
$links = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($links as $link) {
    echo 'End of Link=' . preg_replace('~^.*/~', '', $link->getAttribute('href')) . "\n";
    $images = $link->getElementsByTagName('img');
    foreach($images as $image) {
        echo 'Alt attribute = ' . $image->getAttribute('alt') . "\n";
    }
}
```

> End of Link=168702
>   Alt attribute = Episode 29
>   End of Link=167504
>   Alt attribute = episode 20

**Update:**

```
$input = '<a class="asite-thumbnail" href="/season/path/12345/1/168702"><img src="http://asite.image2432424.jpg" alt="Episode 29"><div class="asite-title">Episode 29</div><div class="asite-info">starwar season 2</div></a><a class="asite-thumbnail" title="episode 20 start war season 2" href="/season/path/12345/1/167504"><img src="http://asite.com/_thumb_dfsdfsdf.jpg" alt="episode 20">';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($input);
$links = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($links as $link) {
    $linkimage['endlink'][] = preg_replace('~^.*/~', '', $link->getAttribute('href'));
    $images = $link->getElementsByTagName('img');
    foreach($images as $image) {
        $linkimage['alt'][] = $image->getAttribute('alt');
    }
}
print_r($linkimage);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [endlink] => Array
        (
            [0] => 168702
            [1] => 167504
        )

    [alt] => Array
        (
            [0] => Episode 29
            [1] => episode 20
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks for your cool solution. May i know how to reference each of end of link and alt attribute values later in my code ? for example i want to construct hyperlinks out of those data (for each set of data )and use end of link data in another get_data() function call before using the processed value inside hyperlink.

Comment: Updated. Also note in your second data set is that a typo with the third `"` on the `href`? e.g. `href="/season/path/12345/1/167504""`.

Comment: Many thanks . the third " is there in sample data set . The actual data is given like that . does it make any problem for result ? i have no control over given data since it is from another website !

Comment: It threw a warning when I was testing `Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): error parsing attribute name in Entity, line: 1 `. Didn't seem to affect the outcome though. Are you generating the HTML/XML, if so I'd correct it.

Comment: I had to filter my input data so that took a while. Now i only want to use end link value and alt value and output hyperlinks for each pair.(where alt value goes for hyperlink name and end link goes for hyperlink url : <a href="http://asite.com/process.php?endlink=167504">episode 20</a> <br />) could you show me how  i can create those hyperlinks?